Content-Security-Policy: which source of constraints is the strictest?
Context
I have this CSP on a page (in a vite react app):
frame-src http://localhost:3080; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost:3080

On the page, an iframe from http://localhost:3080 is embedded. I don't have control over that iframe as it is generated by a 3rd party app running in a container locally.
The iframe's own CSP headers are similar to the following:
default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://maps.google.com https://accounts.google.com https://www.google-analytics.com 'sha256-xxxx=' 'sha256-xxxx=' 'sha256-xxxx='; child-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com; style-src 'self' 'nonce-xxxx' https://accounts.google.com; font-src *; img-src * 'self' data:; connect-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com service.us10.list-manage.com www.google-analytics.com https://service.example.com ; manifest-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none';

The problem
In the main vite app, when I try to adjust the height of the child iframe, I get this error in the browser:
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

also this error (which is interesting as I'm not directly doing anything with https://accounts.google.com):
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-xxxx'   https://accounts.google.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-xxxx='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Question
Is there a CSP, given the above scenario, that the vite app can implement, that will allow the iframe's height to be updated, or is this an impossibility?
I can't tell whether the code is wrong or if this is actually technically infeasible.

This question is similar to: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

while it's conceptually the same, it's different because i) i am not interested in manipulating or accessing the contents of the child frame and ii) it didn't categorically clarify for me whether CSPs alone can circumvent CORS issues when postMessage is not in play, due to lack of control of the iframe. CSPs are usually described as if they're a list of access rules / permissions, so it leads beginners to think "oh, if I add 'unsafe-inline', I'm good right? Only to get egg on your face because other things have a say.  @HalvorSakshaug

If you're running the 3rd party app on a different port to your main application, then you fall fowl of the cross-domain browser restrictions.
The easy solution is to put a reverse proxy (Nginex) in front of both your app and the 3rd party app and server both from the same domain, port and protocol.

Thank you for the concise answer! Which I'll take as an emphatic "no".
OMG nginx. Of course! TY!
